# yq compare only part of files

Tags: linux, bash, continuous-integration, yq

If I have two files, data1.yaml and data2.yaml.

I do not want to compare all conntent of data files. I need to compare only for example version part

```
---
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  version: 0.0.1
  title: yaml validation example
  description: >-
    Some description here.
```

I tried

```
yq compare data1.yaml data2.yaml
```

but it compares whole files

Comment: Which version of yq are you running?

Comment: yq version 4.13.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like this?

```sh
yq eval-all '[.info.version] | .[0] == .[1]' data1.yaml data2.yaml
```

Comment: `yq eval-all '[.info.version] | .[0] == .[1]' data1.yaml data2.yaml`
`false`
Does it mean that query fails or that files are not the same?

Comment: it compares `info:` -> `version:` of the first two documents found in data1.yaml and data2.yaml; if dataX.yaml contains more than one document then you'll need to use something else

Comment: data1 and data2 contains only one document