# yq command in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, continuous-integration, yq

I have a command:

```
yq eval-all "[.info.version] | .[0] == .[1]" api.yaml api_master.yaml <(git show master:api.yaml)
```

and it works fine, returns false or true.

I call this command in bash script on this way:

```
touch api_master.yaml
t=$(yq eval-all "[.info.version] | .[0] == .[1]" api.yaml api_master.yaml <(git show master:api.yaml))
echo $t
```

Then, I call this script in CI pipeline, and get an error:

```
yq: error: argument files: can't open '[.info.version] | .[0] == .[1]': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '[.info.version] | .[0] == .[1]'
```

How this command should be called in bash script so it is executed correctly in CI pipeline

Comment: This probably depends on the yq version; what do you use locally, and in CI?

Comment: ci yq: 2.12.2;
localy: 4.13.3

Comment: @a11eksandar: You have indifferent versions of yq on your CI pipeline and locally. Remember there are two versions of yq out there - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info. The v4 indicates you could be using the Go version - https://github.com/mikefarah/yq and v2 indicates to be a https://github.com/kislyuk/yq. Can you post and check the full output of `yq --version`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With file contents based on [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71661115/yq-compare-only-part-of-files) in mind, you could rewrite this [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq)-based solution to one using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) as

```
yq -n '[inputs.info.version] | .[0] == .[1]' api.yaml api_master.yaml
```

It outputs, just as before, a boolean value based on the comparison of the versions in the two files provided. It does **not** consider any third input (although with `<(git show master:api.yaml)` you provide one), but neither is the mikefarah/yq solution you already had.

Therefore, to check if the versions from **all** provided inputs are indeed identical, use `unique` and check the `length` of the resulting array.

Using mikefarah/yq:

```sh
yq ea '[.info.version] | unique | length < 2' api.yaml api_master.yaml <(git show master:api.yaml)
```

Using kislyuk/yq:

```sh
yq -n '[inputs.info.version] | unique | length < 2' api.yaml api_master.yaml <(git show master:api.yaml)
```

Comment: Nice solution with `uniq`